# ALTER TABLE Yii2 migrate

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, плиз, как на Yii (в миграции)
переименовать таблицу.
Есть ли встроенный метод, 
или надо через sql команду делать
типа такой

```
 \Yii::$app->db->createCommand('ALTER TABLE newsletter RENAME TO mail')->execute();
```

А вот хотелось бы узнать, есть ли встроенный метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть метод для смены названия таблицы. Но хотелось бы предостеречь от некоторых казусов сразу. Рекомендуется не переименовывать таблицу, а создавать новую и работать с новой таблицей вместо старой. Делается это для того, если вдруг придется откатить изменения кода, то не возникнет ошибок  работы с БД. Смысл в том, что структура БД должна соответствовать новому релизу и старому. Так будет меньше проблем на продакшене. А в следующий релиз уже можно удалить старую таблицу.

```
$this->renameTable('table_name', 'new_table_name');
```